# Linq remove where if the value is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

That My Linq query

```
var result = db.APPLICATIONS
.Where(a => Statuses.Contains(a.STATUS_ID))
.Where(a => a.TrackingNo == TrackingNo)
```

`Statuses` is a int list and `TrackingNo` is a nullable int (`int?`).

**Problem:**
If the `TrackingNo` is null then i dont want to run this clause or just skip this condition.

Comment: `var result = db.APPLICATIONS.Where(a => a.Statuses.Contains(a.STATUS_ID) && (a.TrackingNo != null && TrackingNo == TrackingNo))`?

Comment: @Tim i have tried it.  Thats not working! Entity is not grouping the condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ queries can be built in multiple steps:

```
var result = db.APPLICATIONS
    .Where(a => Statuses.Contains(a.STATUS_ID));

if (TrackingNo != null)
{
    result = result.Where(a => a.TrackingNo == TrackingNo);
}
```

Note that if you have a `Select` (a projection), you probably must build the query in multiple steps in multiple variables:

```
var result2 = result.Select(a => new { a.STATUS_ID });
```

with the `result2` "built" after the `if`.

Comment: this will be "built" or this get all "applications that contains status_id" and then filter them if trackingno is not null? This will be an issue for large queries?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli It depends on where the `null` is. If `Statuses` is `null` you'll get a `NullReferenceException`. If  `a.STATUS_ID` is `null` there won't be an error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I mean (Sorry for my english) is this. Suppose that for first query you get 1M records and for the second query only 3. There will be in memory 1M records or only 3? I think it will execute to the db, then get the 1M records, then filter that 1M into 3. There is any chance the execution can be one done you have the linq? Like a "preparation" ?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli The query will be executed when there is a First, FirstOrDefault, Single, SingleOrDefault, Count, Any, ToArray, ToList, or when a foreach is executed on the result of the query. LINQ is based on "deferred execution". Only the methods I named (and some others) cause the execution of the query

Answer (score 3):

You can check a nullable int by using its "HasValue" property.

```
var result = db.APPLICATIONS
    .Where(a => Statuses.Contains(a.STATUS_ID))
    .Where(a => a.HasValue && (a.TrackingNo == TrackingNo))
```

This will cause it to evaluate the "HasValue" prior to checking the value itself. If HasValue return false, then it will never evaluate the rest of the expression (and thus not cause NullReferenceException).
If it is of type "int?", then this will work.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `&&` condition and check `null`. And you can use 1 `where` condiiton here why second `where`.Pls try this:

```
    var result = db.APPLICATIONS
                 .Where(a => Statuses.Contains(a.STATUS_ID) 
                 && a.TrackingNo!=null 
                 && a.TrackingNo == TrackingNo)
```

Comment: This is so wrong

Answer (score 2):

You should first check the values of the filtering parameters before trying to add more stuff to the store expression. This would only apply the Statuses and TrackingNo filtering if the nullable TrackingNo has a value. Otherwise it will return all APPLICATIONS as IQueryable.

```
var result = db.APPLICATIONS.AsQueryable();

if (TrackingNo.HasValue)
{
    result = result.Where(a => Statuses.Contains(a.STATUS_ID) && a.TrackingNo == TrackingNo);
}

return result;
```

Alternatively, this would check if you have any statuses to apply and the tracking separatedly.

```
var result = db.APPLICATIONS.AsQueryable();

if (Statuses != null && Statuses.Count() > 0)
{
    result = result.Where(a => Statuses.Contains(a.STATUS_ID)); 
}

if (TrackingNo.HasValue)
{
    result = result.Where(a => a.TrackingNo == TrackingNo);
}

return result;
```

Or third option, as it is unclear what you really wanted. This would apply the statuses filtering always and tracking only if it is available

```
var result = db.APPLICATIONS.Where(a => Statuses.Contains(a.STATUS_ID));    

if (TrackingNo.HasValue)
{
    result = result.Where(a => a.TrackingNo == TrackingNo);
}

return result;
```

Comment: Thanks for the Info. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just make it return everything if the value is null like:

```
.Where(q => id != null ? q.Id == id : true)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).